# Multiplication in Velocity template

Tags: java, velocity

I got guide lines to do this

```
#set( $foo = $bar + 3 )
#set( $foo = $bar - 4 )
#set( $foo = $bar * 6 )
#set( $foo = $bar / 2 )
```

so I tried these nothing works please help

```
"#set( $foo = $pod.totalprice * $pod.ordqt)$foo "
```

it gives  $foo  as result

```
 "$pod.totalprice * $pod.ordqt"
```

Please help me to know this work.
this gives 100.00 * 13213

Comment: down-voter if you have sense do the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on an older version of Velocity (for example, [1.4](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.4/user-guide.html#Math)) only integer arithmetic is allowed.